# Inequality of Cardinality of Subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ sets such that $A  \subset B$. How can I prove that $|A|<|B|$ (where $|X|$ denotes the cardinality of the set $X$)? Note: A and B are finite sets.)

Comment: That's not true. For instance, $\Bbb N\subset\Bbb Z$, but $|\Bbb N|\not<|\Bbb Z|$. You should change it to $\leq$. As for how to show it, what is your definition of $\leq$ when it comes to cardinalities?

Comment: I was going to say the same as @Arthur: Are your subsets finite? If so, this is true. If they are infinite, not necessarily so, as Arthur pointed out.

Comment: @gary yes, I forgot that. The sets are finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the finite case, if $ A \subset B$ in a strict sense, then there is an $x$ in $B-A$. Let then $A$={$x_1,...,x_n$} , while $B$={$x_1,...,x_n, x_{n+1},.., x_{n+j}$}, so that $|A|=n$ while $|B|=n+j> n$

Comment: Thank you! The way you did it is very easy to visualize.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: I really like it, thanks!

Comment: No problem. You can select it as an accepted answer or write an answer by yourself, so we can close the question?

Answer (score 3):

This reasoning works for $B$ finite.

$A \subset B \implies \exists b\in B \cap A^c$. Now consider the function

$$f:A \rightarrow B$$ such that $$f(a)=a$$

This function is not surjective  so $|B|>|A|$